# how to make an object like a flat?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I am new to Blender.

According to my toturial, I have to create an abject like a flat.

[image]

He hit <kbd>F</kbd> and the object changes,
but when I hit <kbd>F</kbd> in my object, it does not change

[image]

I am using the blender 2.81

Comment: Hello :). Check the video again, he probably just inset the top face by pressing **I**, not F.

Comment: hello :) . in the first picture you can see he hit F.I mean in the left of the picture.

Comment: Sure. He hit *F* (to add the top face) while in *Edit mode*. Timestamp [10:02](https://youtu.be/7w-m13ykLN8?t=602).

Comment: oh.What a bad mistake :( . thank you :)

Comment: No problem :). Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because you have 'subsurface' modifier enabled.
What subsurface modifier does is basically adds extra geometry to your mesh.

In your case, the type is set to Catmull-Clark which in short will basically smooth out your mesh.

So if you start with a basic cube

[image: Default cube]

and apply the modifier on it, it will smooth it out and it will start to resemble a circle 
[image]

Now an easy way to make the object look like what you want it to be is add extra vertices where you want the detail. So if I were to add some extra vertices at the corners of the cube it will start to resemble the cube again
[image]

Now if you understood this you would have guessed you need to add extra geometry in your mesh at the top of your coffee(or water? depends on how far you are in that tutorial)

An easy way to add geometry to a closed loop is the inset tool(hotkey I), this tool basically makes another smaller loop inside the loop and connects the vertices.
[image]